# Extracting Trendlines from given data sets using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am having to create 4200 trendlines equations in both linear form and polynomial form from a given set of data that I convert into a graph. Once I create the graph is there a way I can automatically grab both forms of trendlines for every data set on the graph and paste it without too much effort?

I have limited knowledge of macros, a bit more knowledge of python and its ability to automate.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do and in what platform. Please specify what format your data is in, how you want to make trendlines, how you intend to graph them, etc.

Comment: So I have temperature data that is logged alongside multiple thermal sensors. These are measurements taken every couple of seconds and I want to to take the data as the temperature is heating/cooling and create a trendline off of that slope and put it into a cell for every thermal sensor

Comment: OK, but also tell us what platform the data is in, and how you plan to create trendlines. Is this data in microsoft excel? free text? How do you anticipate manipulating that data? Are you loading it into python?

Comment: Excel. I would like to be able to select the data that I would like trend lines from and paste it into specified cells

Comment: I personally don't know the answer to your question. However, if you want to get a better response, you should add the tag [excel] to the question and add all this information to the question body. As it stands, it would be difficult for an excel expert to find this.